# How to seed random for QMediaPlaylist

Tags: c++, qt, random, multimedia, seed

QMediaPlaylist's random playback is not really random.

It has same sequence for every application running.

I looked at the source code, and find it use QRandomGenerator::global() to get random.

But when I run `QRandomGenerator::global()->seed(100);`, I got error: `Attempted to overwrite a QRandomGenerator to system() or global().`

Comment: It's because global generator is already seeded. What if you try `QRandomGenerator::global()->generate()` instead?

Comment: @vahancho Thx. My problem. I used Qt 5.9, but query the 5.10 source code. 5.9 used qrand(), but 5.10 used QRandomGenerator. In 5.10, QMediaPlaylist is really random.

Answer (score 0):

Just now I update Qt to the latest version, and found that the QMeidaPlaylist's random is a real random now.

Qt 5.9 used qrand()

Qt 5.10 used GRandomGenerator::global()->bounded()